# PostGIS layer attribute table empty in Quantum 2.0.1

Tags: postgis, qgis-2

I recently installed QGIS 2.0.1 (Dufour) on a Windows 7 PC (64-bit). Today I tried, for the first time since Dufour was installed, to load PostGIS layers into QGIS. I successfully set up a connection and I could load layers into QGIS (using both DB Manager and the AddPostGIS layers tool). However, although in DBManager the tables show that they contain a number of features, I cannot see them in the Preview tab (of DBManager). Moreover, the attribute tables of the PostGIS layers I loaded into QGIS are empty (0 features, and the "show selected only" box is not ticked).

To make sure it wasn't a problem with my database (PostgreSQL 9.1, PostGIS 2.1.0SVN), I uninstalled QGIS 2.0.1 and re-installed 1.8 (Lisboa). In Lisboa, I can see my layers rendered in QGIS and their attribute tables are not empty.

Is this a known problem with version QGIS 2.0.1 or have default settings changed since version 1.8?

Thanks for your help.